# Take date from datepicker and display it in label

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have tried this code:

```
-(IBAction)btn_strtPeriodclicked:(id)sender{
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 0, 0)];
    // ... populate your date picker and format it as you see fit.
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];   
}
```

The pickerView display in but too light color.My questions are:

1. How to make picker view visible properly.
2. how to remove picker view.
3. how to display date in label.

Comment: i added the answer kindly check

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't change the appearance of `UIDatePicker`.
2. You can store it in a property and when you need to remove it from superview call `[datePicker removeFromSuperview];`
3. You need a date formatter to get a string value from date. Some like this:

   ```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
   [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
   ```

   And for setting the label with date:

   ```
   self.dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
   ```

Comment: I am unable to select date from picker view..

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)btn_strtPeriodclicked:(id)sender
    {
        UIDatePicker* datePicker1=[[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 290,  self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
        datePicker1.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
        [self.view addSubview:datePicker1];
        datePicker1.hidden = NO;
        [datePicker1 addTarget:self 
        action:@selector(dateChange:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        NSDateFormatter *formate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formate setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yy hh:mm a "];
    //set date too your lable here
        timeText1.text=[formate stringFromDate:datePicker1.date];
     }

-(void)dateChange:(id)sender
     {
             NSLog(@"date is %@",datePicker1.date);
             NSDateFormatter *formate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
             [formate setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yy hh:mm a "];
             timeText1.text=[formate stringFromDate:datePicker1.date];
     }
```

Comment: i am unable to select tha date.should i have to implement touch coding there

Answer (score 0):

you ve to create view for date picker and add your date picker in that view initially hide the frame of datepicker view

First create property and connect with IBOutlet for both view and date picker in .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *datePickerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dobPicker;
```

and viewDIdload() remove the datepickerview

```
-(void)viewDidLoad()
{

[self.datePickerView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

when you do action show the view

```
- (IBAction)showDate
{
UIView *toView;

        self.datePickerView.tag =42;
        toView  =   self.datePickerView;
        toView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 210, 320, 206);
        [self.view addSubview:toView];
}
```

then choose date and convert it to string to show it in label

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [self.dobPicker date];

self.label.text = [formatter stringFromDate:birthday];
```

to hide in that datepickerview add another customview and custom button right hide datepicker action to again remove the view. your view should be like this and create action for done button  [image]

```
- (IBAction)Done:(id)sender {
    for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews])
    {
        if (view.tag == 42 ) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA6Mq.png) here for more info see this video[see this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwHIud_3LUw)